# Alternative numbers populated all to one or zero for ParserInterpreter

Tags: antlr4

Given an ANTLR4 parse tree, I want to be able to learn which rule and which alternative was used at each node of the tree, without having ANTLR generate a full library for me. I was following the examples [in the antlr docs](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/interpreters.md) on interpreters which allows me to get RuleContexts and Rules from ParseTrees, so I can usually get the rule that was used in a ParseTree. However, the altNumber/alternative of the rule that was used to match is either empty or always zero, so I can't figure out which alternative of the rule they used. Any ideas how to grab both?

Theoretically, I should be able to add the following line to my ANTLR4 Grammar:
options {contextSuperClass=org.antlr.v4.runtime.RuleContextWithAltNum]}

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you could share your grammar?  Perhaps supply sample input with the values you are seeing, and what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [JavaDocs for `RuleContext.getAltNumber()`](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/RuleContext.html#getAltNumber()):

> For rule associated with this parse tree internal node, return the
> outer alternative number used to match the input. **Default
> implementation does not compute nor store this alt num. Create a
> subclass of ParserRuleContext with backing field and set option
> contextSuperClass. to set it.**

Is it possible that you are asking to know which Context type you are currently on as you navigate the tree?

```
parserTreeNode.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

Comment: So ANTLR provides a class called "RuleContextWithAltNum" that can set and get the alt number, but it's not much help if I can set it myself: I'm wanting for ANTLR to set it when it parses a rule.

Comment: I subclassed the RuleContextWithAltNum (and used that class for the option) and added a `System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimple()+":"+altNum);` after calling the `super.setAltNumber(altNum)`.  When I did this, I got alternative numbers on most of my rules, but always got `1` on my `expr` rule (and I used many of those alternatives).  It's writing values, but doesn't seem completely reliable.  Just to be clear, 0 and 1 would be the most common values unless you have top level alternatives on a parser rule.

Comment: re: the previous message, I just did this on an existing grammar and was not using the interpreter.  If time permits, I may try that tomorrow, It's quite possible that the interpreter does not call the `setAlt()` method like the generated code does.

Comment: I'm guessing that too. Might try some other, non-ANTLR solution to this: The alt numbers are really important for building a parse tree because I need to figure out which rule alternative was used at any point in the tree.